# Cycles Rendering "Explodes" Model

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I am sure someone out there has experienced this issue, but without knowing exactly how to describe what is happening I wasn't entirely sure how to search it. Basically, everything looks great using Eevee, but when I switch to Cycles...things get strange. I am including a screengrab. [image]

This never has happened before using my Mac, but I recently got a PC and this is the first model I have done on it so I am not sure if there is a setting I have gotten wrong. As this is my first model I have not altered any settings personally.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like your material is set to *Displacement and Bump* in Cycles, check here.

[image]

Setting to *Bump Only* will use the displacement data as a normal map without affecting the mesh.